# Why was Ophelia psychologically ill in the Shakespearean play Hamlet?

Tags: william-shakespeare, hamlet

In the Shakespearean play Hamlet Ophelia became psychologically ill.

Was it because of Hamlet's behavior or how society treated her or what's the real reason behind her sudden illness?

Did Shakespeare leave any reference to the reason behind her illness?

Comment: It's most likely due to Hamlets behaviour; but then Hamlets behaviour is due to the corruption of the Danish court ie 'something's rotten in the state of Denmark'; state can be taken to mean both the state as represented by the court, or more widely as in Danish Society - but there's precious little of that within the context of the play itself.